# Active Collab API - getting all time records for a particular project for all users

Tags: php, activecollab

I'm using the php wrapper for the Active Collab API to try and get all of the time records for all users on a particular project.

The form of my query is for example:

```
print_r($client->get('projects/9/time-records/')->getJson());
```

I am only seeing the time records for me for this project. What do i need to do to see the time records for everyone on this project - is it a user issue?

My assigned user roles for my account are:

- Member
- Extra permissions: Start projects, manage people, and use reports

Thanks!

Comment: I'll update the answer below with more info if you tell me more about what you are building.

Answer (score 0):

API response for `/projects/9/time-records/` route return all time records only if you are:

1. Owner
2. Member who is also set to be a project leader (little crown icon on project's People page)
3. Client and project is configured to let clients review tracked time and expenses

In all other cases, including the one that you described above, Active Collab will only return your time records. It's a data privacy feature.

Without more info from your end (asked in comment), only thing that I can suggest is to ask Owner in your account to give you more permissions in the given project.